# java Run.exec not working to move the content from one folder to another

Tags: java, batch-file

I unable to copy the zip content from one windows system (eg: cat300) to another windows system (cat400) using the below code.

PROBLEM is "fullRegFolder" contains "Test.zip" which is in (cat300 machine) and which I need to move to "radbatDir" which is in another 
windows system.

My configuration.xml shows as below:

```
<AutomationTestServer>
    <!--Destination and credentials for where the automation testing should  be done -->
    <Host>cat200</Host>
    <User>test</User>
    <Password>xx</Password>
    <JavaHome>C:/abc/Web/AppServer/java</JavaHome>
    <RadBatInterface>C:/Rad/UT2122/RadBatInterface</RadBatInterface>

</AutomationTestServer>
```

In my java code  calling as below

```
String fullRegFolder = PropertyHolder.getProperty ("SmokeCompletetTestFolder");

     // Lets copy the file to the Server.
       String radBatDir=PropertyHolder.getProperty("AutomationTestServer.RadInterface");
    radBatDir = radBatDir.replace('/', '\\');
    fullRegFolder = fullRegressionFolder.replace('/', '\\');
    pr = rt.exec("copyTestToWindows.cmd "+fullRegFolder+"\\Test.zip " + radBatDir);
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

    line=null;
    while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {                
        logger.debug(line);
    }
    exitVal = pr.waitFor();
    logger.info("Copy to Server completed with exit code "+exitVal);
```

copyTestWindows.cmd:

```
@echo off
  @echo Copying Test Content to Server

  IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO testContentNotExist

  IF NOT EXIST %2 GOTO radBatDirNotExist

  copy /Y %1 %2

 goto success

 :testContentNotExist
 @echo The test content %1 does not exist
 exit 2


 :radBatDirNotExist
 @echo The rad Bat Directory %2 does not exist
 exit 2

  :success
 @echo The test content %1 successfully copied to dir %2
```

Please help on this:
  error shows : radBatDir does not exist

Comment: Change your program to evaluate and print out the expression `"copyTestToWindows.cmd " + fullRegFolder + "\\Test.zip " + radBatDir`  ... and tell us what it prints.  (I suspect that this is an argument splitting problem.)